# Error while building OBS from source code | CentOS 8

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, cmake

I've a problem with [OBS source code](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases/tag/25.0.8), because it isn't detecting [ffmpeg](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/rpmfusion-free-updates-x86_64/ffmpeg-4.2.3-4.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) who's installed on my computer.

```
[mlodybukk@localhost build]$ cmake -DUNIX_STRUCTURE=0 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${HOME}/obs-studio-portable" ..
-- OBS_VERSION: 0.0.1
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:227 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIBRARIES
  FFMPEG_AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS avcodec avdevice avutil avformat)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindFFmpeg.cmake:151 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  deps/media-playback/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mlodybukk/Pobrane/
```

Edit 1: After installation of ffmpeg-devel and some other required codecs I got an error:

```
CMake Error at UI/CMakeLists.txt:59 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Svg.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Svg", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Svg" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5SvgConfig.cmake
    qt5svg-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Svg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Svg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Svg"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mlodybukk/Pobrane/obs-studio-25.0.8/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mlodybukk/Pobrane/obs-studio-25.0.8/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[mlodybukk@localhost build]$
```

How can I repair this?

Comment: How did you install ffmpeg?

Comment: I've installed ffmpeg from RPM Fusion repository

Comment: Did you install `ffmpeg-devel`?

Comment: Hi. I didn't have it, but after installation of ffmpeg-devel i got an next error. Check my edited post to see it. (I've marked this as "Edit 1:")

Comment: Probably needs some Qt5 devel packages. I’d have to search to find out which.

Comment: I installed `qt5-devel` and OBS is working perfect. Thank you for supporting me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, OBS has needed some packages which I didn't have on my disk. List of packages which are required to build OBS and installation progress are on the [OBS HELP](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#red-hatfedora-based-build-directions) page, namely:

```
sudo yum install \
   make \
   gcc \
   gcc-c++ \
   gcc-objc \
   cmake \
   git \
   libX11-devel \
   mesa-libGL-devel \
   libv4l-devel \
   pulseaudio-libs-devel \
   libspeexdsp-devel \
   x264-devel \
   freetype-devel \
   fontconfig-devel \
   libXcomposite-devel \
   libXinerama-devel \
   qt5-qtbase-devel \
   qt5-qtx11extras-devel \
   qt5-qtsvg-devel \
   libcurl-devel \
   systemd-devel \
   ffmpeg \
   ffmpeg-devel \
   luajit-devel \
   python3-devel \
   mbedtls \
   mbedtls-devel \
   swig
```

Thanks for help! (jsbillings helped me the most. Thank you!)