# How can I uninstall obs-studio built from source code | CentOS 8

Tags: centos, make, uninstall

How can I uninstall [obs-studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases/tag/25.0.8) built from source code from my CentOS 8 machine? It was built from source code - without the browser - and doesn't work on this PC.

When I'm trying to uninstall OBS I'm getting an error:

```
[mlodybukk@localhost ~]$ cd ~/Pobrane/obs-studio-25.0.8/build/
[mlodybukk@localhost build]$ sudo make uninstall
[sudo] password for mlodybukk: 
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
[mlodybukk@localhost build]$
```

`make -n install log`:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'deps/jansson/lib/libjansson.a', needed by 'libobs/libobs.so.0'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:452: libobs/CMakeFiles/libobs.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
```

I've installed its binary file in `/home/mlodybukk/obs-studio-portable/bin`. And it has to be launched there

Comment: So, this version of OBS is not working fine with my PC, but I cannot found a command for uninstall this.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to the site. Your question is unclear. Did you built it with, or without browser source? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/597632/edit) your question to include the steps you took to install it. You can also check [this](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#red-hatfedora-based-build-directions)

Comment: I've edited. I've built without browser

Comment: You could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/87112).

Comment: `sudo make uninstall` is not working :(.

Comment: Where are you running the command? What's your `pwd`?

Comment: I am trying to uninstall in build folder. /home/mlodybukk/Pobrane/obs-studio-25.0.8/build

Comment: [mlodybukk@localhost ~]$ cd ~/Pobrane/obs-studio-25.0.8/build/
[mlodybukk@localhost build]$ sudo make uninstall
[sudo] password for mlodybukk: 
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
[mlodybukk@localhost build]$

Comment: Instead of constantly adding new comments, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/597632/edit) your post. To improve the quality of your future posts make sure to read the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) page. Also did you try `make -n install` as mentioned in the post I told you? It's manual intervention, but, it might be the only choice you got.

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 94017 :(

Comment: I've added make -n install log

Comment: Coming from https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/597072/117549, just for context/history.

Comment: OBS didn't work fine on my PC (I could not record any video). Thanks for help in building it. ;)

Comment: I'll back in obs-studio from repo. It is working fine and i'll stay there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597632/how-can-i-uninstall-obs-studio-built-from-source-code-centos-8#comment1115653_597640) that

> OBS has binary file in `/home/mlodybukk/obs-studio-portable/bin`

Remove the directory `/home/mlodybukk/obs-studio-portable` and its contents and it's likely you'll successfully remove the entire package. It's not "installed" as such since you've chosen the portable version.

Don't forget to check *before* you remove the directory that this is correct

Comment: Thanks for help! I've gave you accepted answer, have a nice day :)

Answer (score -1):

`# rm $(which obs-studio)`

The `which` command is finding where the binary is. So `which obs-studio` would print something like `/usr/bin/obs-studio`. The `rm` command is removing that binary. If that doesn't work, replace `obs-studio` with `obs`.

Or just remove the binary that you run.

Comment: doesn't work ;(

Comment: what was your issue. did you try with sudo or root?

Comment: sudo and root has the same permissions. Source code OBS doesn't create binary file in /usr/bin.

Comment: what about /usr/local/bin

Comment: OBS has binary file in /home/mlodybukk/obs-studio-portable/bin. And it has to be launched there

Comment: Uninstalling a package means much more than simply removing an executable.